# Are there any good command line tools for web browsing non development purposes?

Tags: php, html

After doing about a day of research, [and finding that this article seems to have the most up to date information](https://itsfoss.com/terminal-web-browsers/), I am coming to the unfortunate conclusion that what I seek may not be possible. Drowsh seems to be down at the moment so it appears that my only other lead is a no go. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with hyper V.

Note, a lot of those web browsers probably work, but, when it comes to more complicated websites that require you to post data to a form, such as a login and username and password, I am having less luck and it is becoming less reliable.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Questions that ask for opinions (are there any good...) are off topic here.

Comment: I tagged the question with PHP and HTML, since I tagged it with PHP, and, I talked about needing to send post data to URLs, you should get an idea that I was not simply asking, is X browser good or not. Most browsers for the internet that are modern are objectively good. The ones that exist for the command line are objectively not good by usual metrics. If you're asking can you see a logical expression of text and interact with different areas on the page, it would not hold up to it. Many pages do not work, leaving the user in a tailspin.

Comment: @Jake Browsh is working from here: https://www.brow.sh/downloads/ and ran after a fashion on my setup. Looks like a work in progress...

Comment: @andrew.46 I’m using Falkon in the meantime until there is something in the command line is better. For Linux, I need something that is light weight and runs JavaScript. I don’t want an over opinionated browser that’s full of bloatware.

Answer (score 1):

Web (web browser for GNOME) is a simple yet powerful GNOME web browser targeted at non-technical users. Its principles are simplicity and **standards compliance** (which is why I'm suggesting that you try Web instead of a command-line web browser). The installed size of Web is only 5.7 MB.

Simplicity is achieved by a well-designed user interface and reliance on external applications for performing external tasks (such as reading email). Simplicity does not mean less features; Web has everything a modern web browser is expected to have.

Standards compliance is achieved on the HTML side by using the WebKitGTK+ rendering engine (which is based on the engine used by Google Chrome and Safari), and on the user interface side by closely following the GNOME Human Interface Guidelines (HIG) and by close integration with the GNOME desktop.

To install Web in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install epiphany-browser
```